# Laravel Put/Patch Request

Tags: php, laravel, postman

Im trying to do a Put/Patch Request, I am using Postman, this is my current Code:

```
class CustomerController extends Controller
{


public function getAllCustomer()
{
    return Customer::get();


}

public function addNewCustomer(Request $request)
{
    $validatedData = $request->validate([
        'Title' => 'required',
        'Name' => 'required|max:255',
        'Surname' => 'required|max:255',
        'Email' => 'required',
        'Phone' => 'required',
        'Password' => 'required',
        'dateofBirth' => 'required'
    ]);

    return \app\model\Customer::create($request->all());
}


public function update (Request $request , Customer $id)
{
    $id->update($request->all());
}
```

And this my route:

```
Route::put('Customer/{id}' , 'CustomerController@update');
```

Im trying to insert some Parameters into Postman, but I think the way I do it is not correct, right now I do it like this:
[image]

Im not getting any Errors, but nothing is happening, maybe somebody knows a solution.
I want to Change the Name of the customer.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `x-www-form-urlencoded` for body in postman.

Comment: What should I type in key, value and description?

Comment: key = name, value = Hans, would that be correct? Because this didnt work

Comment: You can keep empty the Description. Just type "name" in Key field and type "Hans" in Value field. If it is not working so far, try to add {{ method_field('PUT') }} in form body

Comment: Im not  using a form Body, only using postman, maybe anymore tips?

Comment: ok then, pass "_method":"PUT" as additional parameter with your other parameters in postman. Then request it as "POST" not a "PUT" request.

Comment: How can I pass a method PUT as an additional Parameter on postman? How does that work?

Comment: {
  "name" : "Hans",
  "_method" : "PUT"
}